# HttpSession with only one Servlet

Tags: java, html, session, servlets

I am creating a Webapp and struggeling with how to manage the Session on my app.

I have one Servlet which is requested by more HTML files via AJAX Calls.
When the user logs in want to create a session and manage this session for the whole app till he logs out.

How can i achieve this?

Shall i make a method on the server which every HTML files calls first after login where check if the session is not null or null?

Comment: What server or container do you use?

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to do. What does "manage this session" mean? You just call request.getSession() and there you are: you get the session.

Comment: yeah but don't i have to check every time i request the server if the session is set? 
Because how else should i know who this request came from?
Or in other words: how can the client know if the user is logged in over more sites then? because if the user user is logged out he shouldnt be able to request the pages

Comment: There is always a session, even for unlogged/new users. Servlet container creates one automatically (using cookies or URL parameter to assign a browser with the session). If the user logs in, you can store the user name (or your own User object) into the session, and remove it on logout. But you cannot use the session itself for authorization.